# Gitlab CI/CD Spring boot Mysql sample Build and db connection successful but Junit test failing with Unknown database issue..! (DB exist)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, yaml, gitlab-ci

**Applying CI/CD With Spring Boot MySQL Gitlab**

I'm created very basic Spring boot crud application with MySQL, What I need to implement is Gitlab CI pipeline to automate my build and execute unit test cases for each and every commit into my gilab repository. What I did so far included in following. Build and db connection successfully executed but junit test cases fail with following error codes,

> [Full Error code](https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-gprd-artifacts/47/27/472783ef6c7433b81a3ecc0c7d0e390854dfee1e6db92e7e81b0c33a30c16dec/2020_11_03/826540722/908038071/job.log?response-content-type=text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&response-content-disposition=inline&GoogleAccessId=gitlab-object-storage-prd@gitlab-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=WkncXw1mbLAfh12VrJwZmDYU13asEv8nVuftDz6%2FVaKX40O2ErneWAIsWsAV%0AorzsKxEZHF1whoj0Y3kmxn2EvqsjRI1D%2BtUibcTXRK5EoDxsCLFu1GtQ2V6D%0Ajb0sOuds0w02nS1DeObmiYtxF4VhuTUi1fuWqR%2FRHGiUOKagVm4L59Q01a5d%0AId3LPd0xTrdEyr7gzNB6pC%2B9D7zebsz89xEjWciuHUYgo%2FoZyGv4d%2FFrBL6A%0A3G7WawiBp8bLxcgPSdNiYGb%2B%2BFl40DnHFfDpjrMUl1qREmVnpioRSamZFGpT%0ALxI1IX0XW0lyJzEGXJ7EdvUO49KjUCvaTq0Tz141Bg%3D%3D&Expires=1604389893)

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'demodb'
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-
```

**Please collaborate to following issue**

https://gitlab.com/letsknow101/springboot-demo-maven/-/issues/1

application.properties

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/demodb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=JST&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=hbstudent

# Hibernate

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update




# Logged in command line to see sql error and jdbc exception
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

**.gtlab-cl.yml**

```
after_script:
 - echo "Clean up activity can be done here !."

services:
 - mysql

stages:
 - build
 - connect
 - test

variables:
 MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
 MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
 MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME: demodb
 MYSQL_DATABASE_SCHEMA: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/static/sql/demodb.sql" 
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hbstudent

cache:
 paths:
  - .m2/repository/
  - target/

build:
 stage: build
 image: maven:latest
 script:
  - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile

connect:
 stage: connect
 image: mysql
 before_script:
  - mysql --version
  - apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends mysql-client
 script:
  - echo "create database $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME < $MYSQL_DATABASE_SCHEMA
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql -e "show databases; use $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME; show tables;"

test:
 stage: test
 image: maven:latest
 script:
  - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
```

[image: required database "demodb" exist]**strong text**

[image: Build and connection successful]

[image: Test fail with : Unknown database 'demodb' error]

Comment: Finally I got the answer, I'll update it here soon.....!

Comment: Soon :) 4 years is enough ?